# Dell Inspiron 5502 laptop won't boot with Team Group DDR4 ram

Tags: boot, laptop, memory, bios

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 5502 Laptop with 11th Gen Intel Core i7 CPU and 12GB of RAM.

I want to upgrade the RAM so I bought two Teamgroup Elite TED416G3200C22-S01, DDR4, PC4-25600 (3200MHz), CL22, 16GB memory sticks from two different stores since the first store only had one left.

After installing them the laptop wont boot, only the keyboard lights up and I get a blank screen. I tested each one by themselves on each of the memory slots and the same happens.

After installing the original RAM sticks the laptop boots normally.

The Team Group site says that memory is compatible with Inspiron 5000 series laptops.

Could both memory sticks from different stores be defective? I have never gotten a DOA ram stick before, altough it's the first time I buy Team Group ram.

The laptop came with a Samsung 4GB DDR4 3200Mhz and a Hynix 8GB DDR4 3200MHz ram sticks.

Anything else I should test before returning them? Maybe some UEFI Bios setting that could be preventing them from booting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to return the memory immediately.  Their claim it should work does not ring particularly true given neither module works.

BIOS normally just limits the total amount of memory but you are just replacing existing memory as a test.

Return it before it is too late because you may need the refund to purchase different memory such as the Samsung memory you already have.

Comment: Yes I'm going to follow your suggestion, I got in touch with the stores to start the return process. One of the stores suggested I try  placing the ram on the floor for 30 minutes to "release the ram static" and then try again. I had never heard of that and doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have not heard of that suggestion to fix a memory module.